# How to update URDF character joint state using openni_tracker

Tags: ros, kinect, urdf, openi-tracker, joint-states

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to develop a simple kinect demo that consists in standing in front of a kinect and after that, start control the movents of a simple URDF character.

To do that, I planned to subscribe to the /tf topic and obtain the user's joint position and angles published by the openni_tracker node so that I could update the URDF character's joint positions according to the user's movement. Something similar to what is done in [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher).

How could I "convert" the quaternions published by the openni_tracker node into some understandable representation for the [sensor_msgs::JointState](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html) joint_state function?

Thanks for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42127/how-to-update-urdf-character-joint-state-using-openni_tracker/) by [arturbp](https://answers.ros.org/users/3069/arturbp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you name the links in your urdf file identical to the TF frame names that are published by the kinect tracker. rviz places the links always based on the tf frames, not based on any joint states.

On the PR2, the [robot_state_publisher](http://ros.org/wiki/robot_state_publisher) node subscribes to the joint_states topic and publishes the tf frames of all links specified in the urdf. Rviz then just uses tf.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3